# I'm seeing symbols instead of letters in the awesome hotkey page

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, awesome

When I open the hotkeys page via menu in awesome (on my Arch Linux system), the descriptions of the hotkeys appear as symbols

[image: Screenshot of hotkey window in Awesome WM]

which makes me think there is something wrong with the fonts on my system. Also when I open GVim (but not when I open vim in the shell) I have to change the font from Monospace to something different to not only see symbols.

What I tried to do:

- googled for it ("awesome font" -_- )
- searched through various [do](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/)c[um](https://awesomewm.org/doc/manpages/awesome.1.html)e[nt](https://awesomewm.org/doc/manpages/awesomerc.5.html)a[ti](https://awesomewm.org/doc/manpages/awesome-client.1.html)on for "font"
- searched "font" in the `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua` (nothing special found)
- looked at my `~/Xresources` file (own configuration but nothing with fonts)
- checked `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` (seems standard, then searched for the file local.conf which I don't seem to have at all)

I'm running out of ideas and would really appriciate any help here!

Comment: Don't know how it's supposed to look like, but it's possible it was designed to work with powerline fonts. Suggest you to install one and try.

Comment: Maybe late answer. Can help others.. But what will help is to check if you have fonts installed. (`fc-list` ). I could see only squares when installed awesome. Did not have any fonts. So installed all possible fonts (check with : `pacman -Ss font` ) I thought I will use them later anyway.